# postman usage - how to input parameters

Tags: rest, testing, postman

My rest service method demands an input parameter. I want to see data structure via postman. How can I add arguments in postman app? I get the error:

> HTTP Status 500 - The bean encountered a non-application exception;
>   nested exception is: The server encountered an internal error that
>   prevented it from fulfilling this request.

Comment: what url you are using?.what kind of request it is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose that you are doing a POST, or a PUT, you want to add your data in XML or JSON or plaintext to the request.

You need to set the URL, and the right HTTP method. Once you choose, suppose POST, you can edit the data to be sent. I choose the raw input type and write inside it what I want to send to the server.

[image]

You may get 500 as server error due to error in the logic of the offered service, try to encapsulate your entity and send agin the request..

Comment: Thank you. It seems that the problem was on a server side, and not due to the bad postman usage.